# Regex CSS full path

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to regex the fullpath of the css, for example I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/myCssFile.css"/>
```

I would like to regex: `/assets/myCssFile.css`

What I tried is this: `/(?:href)=("|').*?([\w.]+\.(?:css))\1/gi`

but this returns me this: `href="../assets/myCssFile.css"`

Can someone help me out with the regex.

BTW: It is an response text of an ajax request which returns me a string of the html page

Comment: You are using JS where you have so many methods to manipulate the dom elements but still want to parse href value with regex? Why? `el.href` should give you the necessary path.

Comment: Use `href="([^"]*\.css)"`. Then benefit from first capturing group.

Comment: @revo Sorry but I won't run 5 km when I can take a cab.

Comment: @roundAbout to further my previous comment, it depends on whether you're getting late for an interview or are trying to lose some weight ;)

Comment: @revo the question is incorrectly tagged. While regex might be preferable option in other languages but in JS it is a big no to get the property of a element. It does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

`href=\"(.*\.css)"`

This will return `"../assets/myCssFile.css"` in a capture group.

https://regex101.com/r/a44Axz/1

All it is doing is saying:

I am only interested in text within quotes that immediately follows an "href" and only if it is a ".css" file.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but maybe it will help someone. :)

Another regex that matches css paths:
`href[ \t]{0,}=[ \t]{0,}"(.{1,}\.css)"`

This also matches cases when between `href` and `=` exists tabs or spaces or between `=` and css filename.

Also, if you want to match css and javascript filenames in one regex you can use something like this:
`href[ \t]{0,}=[ \t]{0,}"(.{1,}\.css)"|src[ \t]{0,}=[ \t]{0,}"(.{1,}\.js)"`
They are combined by or operator `|`.